# Two dimensional list in a Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

My case: I have a bunch of variables. These variables are shared between all Environments. In each Environment these variables have several values, each value connected to a "EnvironmentVariableSet". The amount of EnvironmentVariableSets vary from Environment to Environment. The number of variables are fixed.

For a given Environment I want to display, in a Grid, all the variables, and for each EnvironmentVariableSet, the value of each variable. Something like this:

Column 1 : The variables
Column 2 : The values of the variable in set1
...
Column N : The values of the variable in setN

The goal is that for each variable, the user can edit the value of that variable in a given EnvironmentVariableSet for a given Environment.

My Models:

```
   public class VariableValues
{
    public int VariableID { get; set; }
    public string VariableName { get; set; }
    public List<EnvironementVariableSetValue> environmentSetValues { get; set; }
}

    public class EnvironementVariableSetValue 
{
    public String EnvironmentVariableValue { get; set; }
    public int VariableID { get; set; }
}
```

My Grid

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(variableValues)
    .Name("EnvironmentVariables")

     //blabla
    .Columns(columns => 
    {
        columns.Bound(v => v.VariableName).Width(50).ReadOnly();

        //I NEED A WAY TO BIND EACH COLUMN TO THE UNDEFINED NUMBER ENVIRONMENTVARIABLESETS WITH VALUES HERE! SOMETHING LIKE THIS
        //columns.Bound(v => v.ValueForSetN).Whitd(50);

    })
    //blabla
```

)

Maybe Im just stupid, but i cant find a good solution for this.

Thanks